# Display Blob image NodeJs React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**Display Blob image**

i want to display blob image store in Mysql database. My nodejs API get data and sent it to react APP where i convert it to base 64 and try to display image. but, it is not displaying. so, how to display blob image in react.

here is Code

```
office_front_pic_preview.value = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64.encode(profile.officefrontpic);

<img src={this.props.office_street_pic_preview.value} />
```

Comment: did you check in chrome dev tool if it's a valid base64 and showing preview

Comment: yes, in console data:image/jpeg;base64,W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd , this is showing

Comment: If you hover over the image it will show preview or copy that code and paste it in omnibar, if it's correct it will show you the image

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,W29iamVjdCBP.....">
```

should be working.

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd" > this is displaying in dev tool